# Bootstrap- Should I put header and left side menu inside container class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, resize, overlay

**CSS**

```
.nav-side-menu {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #2e353d;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #e1ffff;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}


.page-header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #f7f8fa;
    border-bottom: thin #e3e3e3 solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -6px black;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-side-menu"></div>
<div class="page-header"></div>
```

[image: image for left slider over header]

when I resize my browser lesser than 768px , then header is being hidden from view. as left sidebar occupies whole space. So should I put them in `container` class?

Thank You.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: you can see here's more examples that you needs: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

Comment: I want my page to be responsive upto 768 px; after that there should be an overlay for the page.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap have 2 types of containers for wrapping site contents and house our grid system.

first is **container**
,used for responsive fixed width container

second is **container-fluid** for a full width container covering entire viewport.

You can put anything in this depending on your need.

Try this:
 http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_gs_container-fluid&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put always in container class. it is very helpful to you in reponsive design.

Comment: I want my page to be responsive upto 768 px; after that there should be an overlay for the page.

Comment: Not an issue. container or container-fluid class  it better as per your design. you you can achieve you actual result in responsive as well as desktop view

Comment: as per image, my sidebar would be on the header. so i have taken `z-index` for that.  and when i resize it, header is hiding from itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding both sections within a container div, then have a 2 column layout, with the left column using the class col-md-3 and the right column being col-md-9. Then you should be able to add a floating navigation menu to the section you need I'd imagine?

Comment: I want my page to be responsive upto 768 px; after that there should be an overlay for the page.

Comment: Why not just use media queries to only show the overlay on the page for devices over that size?

Comment: I have used the same. it works perfect for sidebar , but not for `page-header`.     `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .page-header{
        overflow: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}`

Comment: try using `position: static;` for sidebar i think

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should use container class. depending on your need, you can use `.container` if you need adaptive and `.container-fluid` if you need fluid

Comment: I want my page to be responsive upto 768 px; after that there should be an overlay for the page.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "overlay for the page". what exactly should be the overlay?

Comment: i mean upto **768px** , it should be responsive. and after that whatever the size of elements , should remain same. window can be overlay to element

Comment: just use `.container` and use media query below 768px where you specify some width for container. like this: `.container { width: 768px; }`

Comment: @BhavinShah https://jsfiddle.net/jbjwgkkx/ take a look if this is what you wanted